# Some Particle Systems glitching for unknown reason only in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I recently created an animation with 4 particle systems and some force fields. It starts out correctly, but at ~frame 60 one of the particle systems starts glitching like this:
Frame 65
[image]
Frame 66
[image]
Frame 67
[image]
Later this happened to the blue and white particle systems as well. I have attached the full 630 frame animation and the blend file. Sorry that it is in the video sequencer screen.
[Video](https://mega.nz/file/cYIAjLDa#9w-yg7jm6rII4n3x7RPvTL4yXAzh_HfERaG7luE0GuY)
[Blend File](https://mega.nz/file/4ARmFLCR#-cJ9YVw1_eg1U5RKwcnanqhj9kqLIDpchHnaJN4PIHk)
[All 630 Frames](https://mega.nz/folder/YEoGWKpK#aKV2BCoc7clPlraZYx5BQQ)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue ... so I would say for two reasons

- Enable *Output Properties > Output > Image Sequence* > **Overwrite**
- or try under *Particles Properties > Cache > Delete All Bakes* and **Bake All Dynamics** again

Comment: It's not the image sequence that is giving the error, as it is showing up during the render process as well... As for baking, Is there a way to bake all 4 particle systems at once? but thanks anyways.

Comment: Since Ovewrite was disabled there could be chance there left some old images, but OK. For Bake - that is what I wrote "Bake All Dynamic" button bakes all at once. I suggested delete all bakes since there could left also some mismatch.

Comment: I have deleted all previous images from the render folder. As for the "Bake all Dynamics,", thanks, I didn't know this existed. Do you know any ways to approximate the size of the bake if I bake it onto my drive? I don't want it to take up system memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood ... if you want to save cache on disk enable "Disk Cache" it will create folder in a file directory ... if you are asking how to make saved files smaller use Compression (Light/Heavy) bellow ... or what are you asking for?

Comment: I was just worried that Bake All Dynamics could only save to memory... That wouldn't go well for me...